# Bootstrap 4 - add a border to rounded-circle img but offset by x pixels

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'd like to add a border around a bootstrap 4 image that has the rounded-circle class but I'd like  the border to be offset by a number of pixels.

I tried:

```
<img class="dashboard-profile-img rounded-circle" src="<?php echo URLROOT.'/public/img/images.jpg'; ?>" width="150px">
<style>
.dashboard-profile-img {
 outline: 4px solid red;
 outline-offset: 15px;
}
</style>
```

But this is just a square.

Could anyone point me in the right direction. Is there a border offset in css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular border and a padding :

```css
img {
  border-radius:50%;
  border:solid red 4px ;
  padding:15px;
}
body {background:linear-gradient(to bottom left, red,blue,yellow,cyan,green,violet,purple,tomato) ;/*whatever for a bg */
}
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/100">
```

if the border needs to overlap what's around, add a negative margins to the image to virtually reduce its size.

```css
img {
  border-radius:50%;
  border:solid red 4px ;
  padding:15px;
  margin:-15px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  position:relative;/*to send on top */
}
body {background:linear-gradient(to bottom left, red,blue,yellow,cyan,green,violet,purple,tomato) ;/*whatever for a bg */
}
```

```html
<hr>
img with a border that simulates outline-offset <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100"> the border should overlap what's around it.
<hr>
```